# How to get user access history for RDS for users coming from postgres driver

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Specifically, I would like to see which users (coming from PostgreSQL Drivers / RDS API) are accessing the specific tables inside RDS.

*I believe that finding users who are accessing RDS API can be done using CloudTrail. I'm unsure about how to go on about postgres driver users.*

Comment: While `ExecuteStatement` calls from the RDS Data API are logged in CloudTrail, the SQL is redacted.

Comment: You can enable the query log on RDS, to capture _all_ queries, but I don't believe that will differentiate between users of the Data API and direct network connections.